# How do I check if a block region is empty?

Tags: blocks, theming

I'm wanting to apply some specific CSS on the condition that a block region is empty. How do I make this check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in you're in a page template you can check your `$page` region variable for an empty an array of block objects.

```
if (empty($page['my_region']) { /*DO STUFF*/ }
```

If you're in another context you can use the [block_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/block_list/7) function to determine this.

```
$blocks = block_list('my_region');
if (empty($blocks)) { /*DO STUFF*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

An update on this. I used the solution at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/73685/56728 as follows

```
  module_load_include('inc', 'block', 'block.admin');
  global $theme_key;
  $blocks = block_admin_display_prepare_blocks($theme_key);
  //test for a named block's (here the help block) visibility
  foreach($blocks as $block){
    if($block['delta'] == 'help' && $block['region'] != -1){
      sdpm($block['delta']. " is visible!");
    }
  }
```

This detects whether the block is visible or not, but does not quite do what I'm after which is to test for the visibility of a given block on the current "page" for the current user. That to me sounds like what block_list() does, but I'm stumped by block_list() as I mentioned above. My "solution" also very likely not the most elegant way of doing things so any help from experts out there would be greatly appreciated. Nat